# slicing column in numpy array and creating new matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have to concatenate columns of numpy matrix to create new matrix. I have 2 codes. One is working fine. Other is giving me trouble. The one working fine is

```
x = np.array(range(24))
x = x.reshape((3,4,2))
y = np.array(range(100,124))
y = y.reshape((3,4,2))
z = np.concatenate((x,y))
```

Now result is 6,4,2 if axis =0 it si 3,8,2 if axis=1 and 3,4,4 if axis=2. But look at another code:

```
a=np.array(([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9])
b=a[:,1] # took one column
c=a[:,0] # again took 1 column
d=np.concatenate((b,c))
```

If I provide axis=0 result is 1x6. If I provide axis=1 it is again 1,6. I want in 1 case 1,6 in another 3,2. ie

```
[2,1],[5,4],[8,7]
```

and in another 2,3 ie

```
[2,5,8],[1,4,7]
```

I am wondering why concatenate is not working for me?

Comment: Check the dimensions of each array that you concatenate.  To use axis 1, they have to have 2 dimensions.  Reshape if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vstack`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.array(([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]))
>>> b=a[:,1] # took one column
>>> c=a[:,0] # again took 1 column
>>> np.vstack((b,c))
array([[2, 5, 8],
       [1, 4, 7]])
```

Use `np.transpose` if necessary

Comment: Hey thanks that works. For 3,2 I took transpose of this  any direct way of getting 3,2?